# Is there a web-page containing a list of LLVM optimizations?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization

I've seen many optimization acronyms, eg.

`dce, inline, constmerge, constprop, dse, licm, gvn, instcombine, mem2reg, scalarrepl`

While I can deduce that `dce` is dead code elimination, I have trouble with many other.

Is there a web-page with a list of LLVM optimizations with descriptions, what exactly each one of them does?

Kind regards,
Roay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LLVM documentation contains a list of [analysis and transformation passes](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html). The ones you list all fall under transformation passes. To elaborate on the sometimes terse documentation:

- `inline` inlines functions (duh!).
- `constmerge` de-duplicates identical constants.
- `constprop` does simple constant folding (only instructions with constant arguments)
- `dse` eliminates obviously pointless memory writes (the equivalent of `a = 1; a = 2;` -> `a = 2;`).
- `licm`, loop invariant code motion, moves calculations which are the same on every iteration out of loops so that they are executed only once.
- GVN is the common acronym for [global value numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_value_numbering).
- `instcombine` replaces multiple instructions with a single equivalent instruction (e.g. the equivalent of `a + 1 + 1` -> `a + 2`).
- `mem2reg` converts stack allocations into SSA registers. Front-ends have it much simpler if they just allocate space for locals via `alloca` and use those as pointers, but the optimization passes work on SSA, so this pass turns as many `alloca`s as possible into SSA.
- `scalarrepl` replaces aggregate types with the individual members (e.g. instead of juggling a struct object with two i32 members, use two i32 registers).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I'll just emphasize the link.